# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal URL with retrofit, hostname = null

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

The GET request to `tenants/client/{hostname}` returns a json object with the property `baseApiHostname`.

```
@GET("api/tenants/client/{hostname}")
Call<HostName> getHostname(@Path("hostname") String hostname);
```

`baseApiHostname` is successful retrieved. That hostname which is used to create the rest of tenant requests from.

```
    Log.v("base url","testing "+preferenceManager.getTenantHostname());
    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(builder.create()))
            .baseUrl(preferenceManager.getTenantHostname())
            .build();
```

I received the error "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal URL".
[stacktrace message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhtmn.png)

After attaching debugger I realized that hostname = null.
[debugger message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywqs2.png)

```
    Call<HostName> call = hostNameApiService.getHostname(tenant);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<HostName>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<HostName> call, Response<HostName> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                String hostname = response.body().getBaseApiHostname();

                preferenceManager.setTenantHostname(hostname);

                retrieveCampaign();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(StartSurveyActivity.this, "Error Retrieving Hostname", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```

Here is the Hostname model class

```
@SerializedName("id")
private String id;
@SerializedName("name")
private String name;
@SerializedName("baseApiHostName")

private String baseApiHostname;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getBaseApiHostname() {
    return baseApiHostname;
}

public void setBaseApiHostname(String baseApiHostname) {
    this.baseApiHostname = baseApiHostname;
}
```

If there's any other detail required that will aid in helping myself and other developers who may have faced a similar problem, please don't hesistate to ask.
Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Can you please include the JSON object you are referring to?

Comment: @bated "baseApiHostname": "https://demo.api.dev.samelogic.com/"

Comment: Does your link has another `.com` at the end of the url and a `}` or ??

Comment: What is the json you are getting back from the server?

Comment: {"id":"e8988d8c-d2d0-4a74-859c-a277f8b7b661"
"name":"Demo"
"baseApiHostname":"https://demo.api.dev.samelogic.com/"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GSON is not successfully serializing any response to the field you're retrieving, so there is some misalign in how you are setting up gson to parse your json result.

Given your object and your sample JSON, your field in JSON is "baseApiHostname" whereas in your object your GSON annotation is for serialized name "baseApiHostName".

Comment: Edited this to give a more succinct anser based off of what was added. SerializedName and the json field don't follow the same case pattern which is why the tenanthostname field is null when serialized.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting null in your Retrofit.Builder for your base URL.  What is the URL for your server?  You need to set that for the first time.  Then you can change it after that if need be but it can't be null the first time.

Comment: @tim.patez this is the dev base url: "https://api.dev.samelogic.com/"
Okay, yes it needs to be changed after, how would you suggest I do that tho, because the 'baseApiHostName' retrieved is what's suppose to be the baseUrl for all other tenant requests.

Comment: Add your code for your HostName java class that represents your JSON.

Comment: Please note that there are two Retrofit.Builder, the one posted is use for setting the baseUrl for all other tenant request and the other uses the dev base url for getting the json object baseApiHostname.

Comment: Post your code in the question and format it correctly.